# Using ReSharper 5.0 in VS 2010 web application project with Telerik controls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, telerik, resharper-5.0, code-cleanup

When using "Cleanup Code" function in ReSharper 5.0, code cleanup removes the aspx page line:

Seems like an issue within ReSharper 5.0. Anyone else having the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the assembly is necessary? I mean do you use any of the controls from that assembly in your mark-up?

Comment: I am using controls from that assembly - that's why I am asking the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Glynn,

I would check to see if the following line is in your web.config in the pages/controls section.

```
<add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
```

If so, then the <%@ Register %> is not necessary and Resharper is taking out the duplicate registration.

Mike